# BizTalk Send File Port To Folder With Ampersand In Name

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a requirement to add a new send port to a send port group in my BizTalk 2013 application. The send port should send to a File location with the destination folder set to **\\ResearchServer\ResearchTeam\R&DReports**

Although I can set the file handler settings to this path I can't save the send port. This is because BizTalk automatically generates a **URI** of **\\ResearchServer\ResearchTeam\R&DReports** which contains the invalid character **&** (ampersand).

Obviously one way to "fix" this would be to rename the folder but this would have serious consequences for other apps and users who access this folder (and is, quite frankly, avoiding the issue rather than finding a fix).

I've also considered creating a dynamic port and then setting the destination at runtime. However this seems extremely complicated and would require downtime on a live server.

I've looked on TechNet and StackOverflow for ideas and it seems I'm the first person to encounter any issues with ampersands in BizTalk file destinations.

Any ideas, please help!

Comment: When does this error appear? I have just tried in my biztalk-2013 administration console and I can create a FILE send port with the URI that you said without any problem. And I tried both inside/outside of a send port group.

Comment: Could you show/describe the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I just tried creating a send port with R&DReports in BizTalk 2013 R2 and had no issue.    If it is the name that is the issue you could create a Share that points to that folder that has a name without a &

Comment: Just note that if you're setting this up in an XML bindings file directly you need to properly escape the character - `\\ResearchServer\ResearcTeam\R&amp;DReports` since `&` is a reserved character in XML.